# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first In Nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm getting product images from this services getting this error in version 3.8:

```
var defaultProductPicture=_pictureService.GetPicturesByProductId(productmodel.Id,1).FirstOrDefault();
productmodel.productImagUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(defaultProductPicture, 75, true);
```

My `GetPicturesByProductId` services is:

```
public virtual IList<Picture> GetPicturesByProductId(int productId, int recordsToReturn = 0)
{
    if (productId == 0)
        return new List<Picture>();


    var query = from p in _pictureRepository.Table
                join pp in _productPictureRepository.Table on p.Id equals pp.PictureId
                orderby pp.DisplayOrder
                where pp.ProductId == productId
                select p;

    if (recordsToReturn > 0)
        query = query.Take(recordsToReturn);

    var pics = query.ToList();
    return pics;
}
```

I don't know why `GetPictureByProductId` faces this error in newer version 3.8. In version 3.7 everything working fine.

Comment: Could you please add your setting file here.

Comment: which setting file. are you talking about setting.txt

Comment: Yes.`setting.txt` which contains connection string.

Comment: DataProvider: sqlserver
DataConnectionString: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=abcDB;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False

Comment: Please add this `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in the connection string

Comment: Thanks working Fine.. Please Mention in answer

Comment: Glad that helped. sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if you execute a query while iterating over the results from another query.

So just add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to the connection string in `setting.txt` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case, setting this, will result in null output for inner query.